# How to redirect users to the last active page before logout after login?

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak-angular for SSO.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular

And now I want to redirect users to the last active page before logout after login.

How could I implement this?

Does keycloak-angular have some build-in mechanisms for handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with `keycloak-angular`, all you need to use to achieve what you want is `Angular Router`, `Angular ActivatedRoute` and `localStorage`.
First of all your `login` and `logout` methods should have the ability to to store and read the last visited route, and you can use `localStorage` to so just that:

Inside your login service:

```
  logout() {
    this.route.url.subscribe(url => {
      // read the last visited route and save it to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('last-route-visited', url[0].path)
      // then logout
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    })
  }

  login() {
    // read the saved route from local storage
    const lastRouteVisited = localStorage.getItem('last-route-visited')
    // then navigate to it
    this.router.navigate([lastRouteVisited])
  }
```

Don't forget to add the service as a provider in your component, because otherwise he won't have access to the last visited route.

Inside the component who uses the login/logout service:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [LoginService]
})
```

Now you can use the logout from your login/logout service:

```
  logout() {
    this.LoginService.logout()
  }
```

Here is the link to a [github repo](https://github.com/encetroc/redirect-last-page) for the full demo

You will also have to adjust the login and logout methods to your own needs, in my example I just saved a simple string representing the saved route to where I want to navigate, but in your case you may need to save complex strings to the local storage, you can use `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Store the path of last active page in a cookie and redirect the user to that page after login using 'Router'